# Hide input simple_form, Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, input-field

I've got a form where some text fields should be visible only under certain conditions. Basically, there's a select list and depending on what's selected, other fields are either showing or not. So by default I need to hide divs that wrap inputs in the form generated by simple_form gem.

Example:

```
= simple_form_for
  = f.select ...
  = f.input :s_n1, :required => true
  = f.input :s_n2, :required => true
  = f.input :s_n3, :required => true
```

It should behave the same as hide() by jqyuery:

```
$("div.s_n1").hide();
$("div.s_n2").hide();
$("div.s_n3").hide();
```

Comment: As it stands, the question is a bit vague, could you elaborate on what problems you're having while trying to hide the input?

Comment: you want to have a sort of a generated field that the user doesn't need to fill in? If so, try hidden_field_tag. If not then sorry, i misunderstud :)

Answer (score 2):

on simple form if you need to make input field as hidden use these code
  <%= f.input :s_n ,:as => :hidden%>
I think its more better than using jquery code

Comment: `:as => :hidden` and `.hide()` is not the same

Comment: Yeah that's not the same, it changed input to type hidden instead

Answer (score 2):

Use simple form `wrapper_html` attribute:

```
= simple_form_for
  = f.select ...
  = f.input :s_n1, required: true, wrapper_html: { class: 'hide' }
  = f.input :s_n2, required: true, wrapper_html: { class: 'hide' }
  = f.input :s_n3, required: true, wrapper_html: { class: 'hide' }
```